# How to work with object using SpriteMask in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make game using sprite mask and have one problem. for example - i have platform, which is not exist in sprite mask [image: https://sun9-32.userapi.com/c851416/v851416709/1dd072/E8Hi6Im0mtI.jpg]

I found OnBecameVisible function, but it works for whole game object, what i need is when i stay on 'nothing' - i should fall down, but at the same time platform should have boxCollider2d to stand on it

```
    private void OnBecameVisible()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enable = false;  // doesnt work for me
    }
```

so what should i do to make object active when they are visible on mask? i mean not only platforms, but some object i could click on when they are visible and couldnt when they are not

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
```

Comment: I dont need to disable collider for all object, olny for part which is in sprite mask now

Comment: Divide it into parts